# How can I update the shipping charge in the checkout page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to update the shipping charge on the checkout page after the shipping information process.

```
$rates = Mage::getModel("checkout/session")->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getAllShippingRates();
        $shippingprice = 10;
        foreach($rates as $rate){
            $rate->setShippingAmount($shippingprice);
            $rate->setBaseShippingAmount($shippingprice);
            $rate->save();
        }
```

Comment: //Try with below link or go through it. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58767/how-to-add-shipping-rate-while-creating-order-programmatically

Comment: This is pretty complex depending on what shipping methods you want to update. Do you want to update the prices for ALL shipping methods available?